# How to specify which method you use in PuLP python?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I'm new to optimisation and python so sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I wanted to use Revised Simplex Method in PuLP and i read in the documentation that there is an option to specify which method the solver uses but i could not find how to do it.

link to the documentation : https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/optimisation_concepts.html

Comment: Depends on the solver. You can pass solver options to the solver.

Comment: okay, so how can i specify for example for solver PULP_CBC_CMD()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the solver COIN-CBC, you can do:

```
 prob.solve(pulp.COIN_CMD(msg=1, options=['primalSimplex']))
```

or

```
 prob.solve(pulp.COIN_CMD(msg=1, options=['dualSimplex']))
```

Notes:

- You should observe somewhat different iteration counts.
- Dual simplex is the default.
- I assume you mean by "revised simplex" the primal simplex method (CBC has no full-tableau simplex so in that sense all Simplex methods in CBC are "revised").
- The interior point method can be selected with `options=['barrier']`.
- For large LPs it may make sense to try out these three methods. I am not sure what these options do for MIP models (it is probably better to trust LP defaults in this case)